# AngularJS : Return a promise which is constructed from the result of another promise in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have the following function defined in a service, in which I use `$http` to get some data and set some of the fields of an object:

```
function getComplexObject () {

    var complexObject = {
        'A': null,
        'B': null
    }
    $http.get('someURI').then(function(data) {
        complexObject.A = data;

        //Do some processing and set B 

        return complexObject;
    })
};
```

So until now I've used a promise with the `$http` service but I don't know how to wrap the function with `$q` so that I can ultimately use it in the following manner:

```
//Using my function as a promise
myService.getComplexObject().then(function (data) {
    this.complexObject = data;
})
```

I've searched for tutorials on angular promises but most of them simply explain what a promise is or do something similar to what I already did, I'm guessing what I want to do is possible but I can't find the right syntax or the right tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `return` in front of the `$http.get(...).then(...)` chain, i.e.

```
return $http.get(...).then(...);
```

This will ensure that the result of `getComplexObject` is a promise that will (when its resolved) contain the value of `complexObject`.

That is exactly what `.then` is designed for - it takes the promise from `$http.get()` and returns a *new* promise that will ultimately be resolved with its own return value instead of the original one.

FWIW, I'd put the declaration of `complexObject` inside the `.then` call - there's no need for it to be in the outer scope and it'll inadvertently cause a closure over that variable.

NB: Also, be careful about using `this` in your final callback - it may not be what you think it is!

Comment: Thank you, this works I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer when possible and about this you're correct I'll use $scope.

Answer (score 0):

You could return a promise and resolve if later (see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

```
function getComplexObject () {

    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var complexObject = {
        'A': null,
        'B': null
    }
    $http.get('someURI').then(function(data) {
        complexObject.A = data;

        //Do some processing and set B 
        deferred.resolve(complexObject);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

Comment: no, this is absolutely _not necessary_.  `.then()` already does this for you!  This is a promise _anti-pattern_.  It actually breaks correct error handling, too.  See https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Comment: Consider the `.catch` case - this code will completely fail to notify the caller if the `$http.get()` call fails because nowhere does it allow for a `deferred.reject()` call.  The result is that this code is actively harmful.

Comment: What about "//Do some processing and set B"? I guess there was a reason for this comment. And of course one must reject the promise on case of an error.

Comment: The "set B" part should be irrelevant as far as the promise handling is concerned.  The problem with this version is that the error handling has to be explicitly added, whereas simply adding the `return` per my answer allows the error to automatically propagate through the promise chain with no additional code.